# Can I declare a function inside a flutter_bloc builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) flutter package to add a calendar with events. I need to declare a function that uses state from bloc. Is there any problem with his approach? Right now it's working but I feel like there is a better solution that I can't think of.

```js
class TableView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TableView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CalendarBloc, CalendarState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        List<Schedule> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
          final calendar = state.days.firstWhereOrNull(
            (calendar) => day.isOnCalendar(calendar),
          );

          return calendar == null ? [] : calendar.schedules ?? [];
        }

        return TableCalendar<Schedule>(
          focusedDay: state.focusedDay ?? DateTime.now(),
          firstDay: kFirstDay,
          lastDay: kLastDay,
          selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(state.selectedDay, day),
          onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
            context.read<CalendarBloc>().add(
                  DaySelected(
                    selectedDay: selectedDay,
                    focusedDay: focusedDay,
                  ),
                );
          },
          eventLoader: _getEventsForDay,
          // calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could place this function inside the bloc itself. So that you could also test the business logic inside the function as well. It will be hard to test this if you are placing this function inside the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the `_getEventsForDay` function into the `CalendarBloc` is a good idea as it will make the code easier to test and maintain. The function can be a private method inside the `CalendarBloc` class. This way, the business logic can be tested in isolation, which will make the tests more reliable and easier to write.

In addition, this also makes the code more modular and separates the presentation logic (the UI) from the business logic (the bloc).

Comment: This function is called by the Calendar builder when it builds calendar rows.

Comment: context.read<CalendarBloc>().getEventsForDay() you can access the function like this.